# How can I make my Windows Form to do and display my database query?

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

I have 3 Tables:

- **Titles:**

  - TitleId (int 6, primary key)
  - TitleName (varchar 50)
- **Authors**:

  - AuthorId (int 6, primary key)
  - AuthorName (varchar 50)
- **AuthorsTitles**  (this is a junction table for Titles and Authors)

  - TitleId (int 6)
  - AuthorId (int 6)

There's a "many to many" relation: A Title may have many Authors, and an Author may have many Titles. This is why I need the junction table.

All I want is to get a Windows form with a **ComboBox** with Titles. The user selects a Title, and the Author or Authors of the selected Title will be listed in a **ListBox**.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition 2008 and SQL Server Express Edition 2008.